# How to improve performance of SSRS PreviewProcessingService while previewing in VS?

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

Since one of the last Sql Server Data Tools updates for Visual Studio 2013, the preview-rendering has changed drastically.

Installed Version: Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - enu(12.0.30919.1)

Visual Studio opens a separate process to render the preview-data, without any output or information. This preview-service is so ridiculously slow when displaying large amounts of data.

For a comparison:

A statistical report that displays around 20 pages of static precalculated data is normally rendered instantly when executed in our production environment.

When previewed in visual studio the exact same report may take up to 40-60 seconds to render.

Is there any way to optimize this sub-optimal behavior? Currently I have to change one tiny layout / grouping thing in around 30 reports and the additional rendering time during development adds up a lot.

Comment: Data Source cache can impact rendering performance. Is the data source settings are the same on both server and designer?

Comment: I'm experiencing huge performance issues as well with the preview feature. While its rendering the report preview, PreviewProcessingService.exe takes all the CPU it can get. I'm on version 12.04.41012.0.

Comment: Thanks for the info and link. Currently I avoid this behavior by reducing the result size, which isn't always possible though. CPU is ok here, on an lenovo i5 one core is at 25% during the result processing.

Comment: Connect bug: 
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1080556/sssr-rep
ort-preview-in-vs-2013-feature-is-really-really-slow-as-compared-to-vs-2008